# How to open new window with vvuetify v-icon vue router?

Tags: vuetify.js

I am trying to open a new page but it cannot. When I click on my home icon, it opens my home page and when click on dashboard it says

> dashboard 'app' has been removed, use '' instead.
>   VToolbar>
>                   at src/components/Navbar.vue
>                    
>                       at src/App.vue

App.vue

```
template>
        <nav>
            <v-toolbar flat app>
             <v-app-bar-nav-icon class="grey--text" @click="drawer =! drawer"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
              <v-toolbar-title class="text-uparcase grey--text">
                  <span class="font-weighted-light">Blue</span>
                  <span>Berry</span>
              </v-toolbar-title>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-btn flat color="grey">
               <span>Home</span>
              </v-btn>
            </v-toolbar>
            <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" app class="indigo">
          <v-list-item >
            <v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>

          <v-divider></v-divider>

          <v-list
            dense
            nav
          >
            <v-list-item
              v-for="item in items"
              :key="item.title"
             router:to="item.route"
            >
              <v-list-item-icon>
                <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-icon>

              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list>
            </v-navigation-drawer>
        </nav>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                drawer:false,
                 items: [
              { title: 'Dashboard', icon: 'mdi-view-dashboard',route:'/' },
              { title: 'Photos', icon: 'mdi-image',route:'/photos'},
              { title: 'Home', icon: 'mdi-home' ,route:'/home'},
              { title: 'About', icon: 'mdi-help-box' ,route:'/about'}
            ],
            right: null,
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Sory type mistake,when i click on home icon itwill open home page,but it cannot work when i click th icons it stay in same page

Comment: You don't have to use router:to just use :to="item.route"

Answer (score 0):

Try to nest every v-list items in a  < router-link />

 Like that

```
<router-link :to="{ name: item.title }">
  <v-list-item>
    ...
  </v-list-item>
</router-link>
```